# PRISM: Creating Pipeline of Async methods

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism

I am wondering if anyone can help me with something here:
I am trying to create a "pipeline" or "queue" of commands [similar to CompositeCommand in Prism] except I want it to be sequential even if the command being executed is Asynchronous in nature.

Basically, I want to string together bunch of Async calls [not at compile time but at run time] and I want something similar to CompositeCommand functionality where I can easily register and unregister calls.

Any help/insight into this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

check out the coroutine implementation in Caliburn Micro.

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation

You can also watch Rob describe coroutines in his video from Mix this year.

http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX15

Or ... if you're allowed to be on the cutting edge, just announced today are the async and await keywords in the next version of the framework.  Read about that here:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112225208/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/10/28/async.aspx)

Hope that helps.